# Launch iPhone setting screen from Application?

Tags: iphone, settings

I am developing an application where i want that upon a press of button iPhone settings screen should open.

Is there any restriction from apple to access it?

Is it possible or not,If yes then how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open the Settings application from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that. However as an alternative you can use [This Framework](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) to mimmick the settings app, so that you can set your settings from the official settings app, or from a in app settings page.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible using public API's.

However there exists a number of frameworks that allows you to access the settings bundle directly from within your application. Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839242/iphone-how-to-put-settings-bundle-seen-through-system-settings-app-into-your-ow) for more information.