# How to switch to specific system setting view from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

My app has a button, when user press it, I want to go to the network setting page of the
system setting app of iOS.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, this page will give you more information on why it is not possible.

[How do I open the Settings application from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application)

It is possible to directly set settings (without going to the page).

[iPhone - how to put Settings bundle seen through System Settings App into your own App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839242/iphone-how-to-put-settings-bundle-seen-through-system-settings-app-into-your-o)