# iPhone Settings

Tags: iphone, settings

Is there any way to access the iPhone/iPod touch settings programatically ?

Thanks.
Biranchi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the user settings can be accessed by reading the property lists stored at `/User/Library/Preferences/`. The Emoji enabler applications all worked by modifying a settings plist in this folder.

<sub>Be careful **not** to delete any settings or leave them in an inconsistent state</sub>

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do this programmatically in an iPhone app?  I am trying to read this plist in code.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: is is still available in ios 6 or 7

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not, also you can't launch the settings app from your own app as these answers explain.

[Programmatically opening the settings app (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736047/possible-to-programmatically-open-settings-app-from-iphone)
[How do I launch my settings bundle from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335965/how-do-i-launch-my-settings-bundle-from-my-application)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about what settings you would like to be able to access. There are API's to get at some information, but general access to the device is prohibited by the sandbox your applications run in.

Comment: How can i turn on or off the airplane mode

Comment: You will not have access to control airplane mode

Comment: as i have read from many posts, i get that it is possible for jailbroken devices and its working fine, but i dont want to do that for jailbroken devices, i want to use private apis(as dont want to put it on appstore)...