# iOS SDK and device settings

Tags: ios, settings

**What does the iOS SDK provide in terms of programmatic access to the device's settings (usually accessed via the Settings app)?**

After reading through Apple's [Preferences and Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) documentation I'm not sure if an app can programmatically adjust the device's brightness or perhaps toggle wifi on/off. I'm experimenting with `NSUserDefaults` right now. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's official public APIs do not allow an iOS app to access General settings in the Settings app, such as the wifi enable.   NSUserDefaults only allows access to those preferences and settings created specifically by that one app for its own use.

Comment: I see. Are apps that mess around w/ plists in `Library/Preferences` usually rejected? Sounds like some fairly popular apps are doing this (stackoverflow.com/a/1335316/22471)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for some settings, by using a private API you can access them.
However, apparently, using these private API's prevents your app from being accepted into the app store.
A Link:
[Access iOS settings from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328545/access-ios-settings-from-code)
Hope this helped! ^_^

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Apparently some apps just modify the appropriate plist files http://stackoverflow.com/a/1335316/22471