# Is there any way to identify a settings as a tab rather than doing it iphone settings menu?

Tags: objective-c

I want to configure text font, size etc inside the application (for example in tabbar) rather than iphone settings menu.. How will I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this stackoverflow question for additional information [How do I launch my settings bundle from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335965/how-do-i-launch-my-settings-bundle-from-my-application)